# How to find most and least significant bits of an unsigned number u64 in Rust?

Tags: rust, bit-shift

Where LSB at index 0 and MSB is at index 63. Similarly it should extend to u32 and other types.

```rust
let my_num: u64 = 100; // 0b1100100
let msb = get_msb(my_num); // 0
let lsb =  get_lsb(my_num); // 0
```

Correction: MSB should be 0 at the 63rd bit, not 1 at index 6

Comment: You can always get the lsb as `my_num & 1`.  As for the msb, isn't it 0 in your example?  It should be bit 63 which is cleared since 100 is much less than 2**63.  That you can get as `my_num >> 63`.

Comment: And more generally, you can get bit number `n` with `(my_num >> n) & 1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As explained in the comments, you get the LSB and MSB of `u64` with `n & 1` and `(n >> 63) & 1` respectively.

Doing it completely generically is somewhat of a hassle<sup>1</sup> in Rust, though, because generics require operations like shifting, masking, and even the construction of `1` to be fully specified upfront. However, this is where the [`num-traits` crate](https://crates.io/crates/num-traits) comes to the rescue. Along with its cousin [`num`](https://crates.io/crates/num), it is the *de facto* standard for generic Rust in the field of numerics, providing (among others) the `PrimInt` trait that makes `get_msb()` and `get_lsb()` straightforward:

```
use num_traits::PrimInt;

pub fn get_lsb<N: PrimInt>(n: N) -> N {
    n & N::one()
}

pub fn get_msb<N: PrimInt>(n: N) -> N {
    let shift = std::mem::size_of::<N>() * 8 - 1;
    (n >> shift) & N::one()
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(get_lsb(100u32), 0);
    assert_eq!(get_lsb(101u32), 1);
    assert_eq!(get_msb(100u32), 0);
    assert_eq!(get_msb(u32::MAX), 1);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3d859904f772dd996dae0fd16d794145)

---

<sup>1</sup> If you're curious about the full version using just the standard library, here is what it would look like:

```
use std::convert::TryFrom;
use std::ops::{BitAnd, Shr};

fn one<N: TryFrom<u8>>() -> N {
    1u8.try_into().unwrap_or_else(|_| unreachable!())
}

pub fn get_lsb<N>(n: N) -> N
where
    N: BitAnd<Output = N> + TryFrom<u8>,
{
    n & one()
}

pub fn get_msb<N>(n: N) -> N
where
    N: Shr<usize, Output = N> + BitAnd<Output = N> + TryFrom<u8>,
{
    let shift = std::mem::size_of::<N>() * 8 - 1;
    (n >> shift) & one()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4958dda9e7d1be3d7084c9b1f6b54d20)